# I cant log into different accounts on the same browser using an identity server with oauth2.0. Can anyone advise on how to do this?

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We have a single identity server that uses oauth 2.0 to authenticate our apis against. We have 2 apis that use the single identity server to get the token.

My issue is that the single identity server using oauth 2.0 redirects with a cookie which is the same for both apis since its coming from the same single identity server. This stops me logging into multiple accounts using the same browser.

Anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution to allow your users to use two different login accounts to login to the two APIs using the same browser? So, you are not planning to do single sign on?

Comment: Good point, thanks - closed